# R DBI connection closed unexpectedly by server + server terminated abnormally before or while processing request

Tags: r, postgresql, dbi, rpostgres

I am using `DBI` and `pqdriver` for Postgres via `RPostgres::Postgres()` to establish a connection like the following.

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), dbname = "my_db", host = "10.10.10.194", port = 5432, user = "my_user", password = "my_password")
```

Using the same connector, I am able to connect to a UAT version of our environment but unable to connect to production - despite all credens etc. being correct.

The error I get is:

*Error: server closed the connection unexpectedly. This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.*

For the life of me, I am unable to understand **how** to debug this issue. I am able to successfully `telnet`, but only while connecting like the above my attempt fails.

**Update 1**

I tried checking with IT/DB admin, and they wonder if this is happening because `dbConnect` is using any proxies to access. Not sure how I can see this?

Also, I tried `traceback` to get the following (I am sure there will be better ways of debugging which I am unaware of...)
[image]

**Update 2**

This is what I get if I run via JDBC:

[image]

Comment: What port are you able to telnet to?

Comment: Does this failed connection attempt leave any messages in the db server's log file?  If not, then this is most likely a networking issue.

Comment: @jjanes thanks for responding. 5432 is the port I tried to telnet in to. And I checked with IT, they are not keeping logs (yikes)...

Comment: Are you able to connect wit another client? E.g. pgAdmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's related to stricter permission settings on your production postgreSQL instance. Even when user/pwd is the same, the production instance might only accept connections from localhost or specific IP addresses. Furthermore, authentication via username/password could be disabled, allowing e.g. only the "cert" method.

Please check /etc/postgresql/VERSION/main/pg_hba.conf (or have it checked/explained to you by your DBA/IT).

Also, it could be due to specific firewall/security settings for your production instance. Which would allow connections only from specific IPs, or it would simply drop all packets from the DBMS to your machine.

HtH